# Integrate external storefront e.g Optimizely with SAP Hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am doing a project that involves integrating Hybris backend with external storefront (Optimizely). As a start, I am trying to run my hybris apis for products, orders, users, carts etc via postman. I believe if I am able to run them, then this integration will be smooth for the Optimizely team. I am a bit new to this so I need just need guidance am I on the right path? Do I need to create any custom extensions using extgen or acc apis? Is there a public postman collection available for hybris apis? I couldnt find any.
Please guide how do this, what steps do I need to follow, do I need to do any customizations in code or just running the existing apis via postman will suffice? I am new to hyrbis so any guidance in the correct direction is really appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this via occ API which exists OOTB. You don't need to create any extension, you just need to configure OAuth on hybrid side. I hope Optimizely has support for OAuth.

hybris has also new Angular based single web page commerce project (https://github.com/SAP/spartacus](Composable Storefront) (new name Composable Storefront). You can check the demo site and anylaze network activities to learn a lot of things.

The occ has out of the box Swagger UI. You can access example one with this [URL](https://20.83.184.244:9002/occ/v2/swagger-ui/index.html).
Swagger UI using Open API to create its UI. So you can directly import the Open API JSON file to [Postman](https://learning.postman.com/docs/designing-and-developing-your-api/importing-an-api/). You can access the above Swagger UI's Open API json with this [URL](https://20.83.184.244:9002/occ/v2/api-docs).

Companies never use hybris with OOTB features and data types. So you need to make extra effort for every project for details.